# MSSQL - Extract second from time

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm new to Microsoft SQL Server. And I wanted to extract second from the time datatype.

I've got experience in PostgreSQL and I extract the second the using this function.

```
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp)
```

But in Microsoft SQL Server, I found this function -

```
DATEDIFF(second, 0, timestamp)
```

Which gives me the second if the time is less the 24 hours.

But when I try a query like this.

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(second, '0:00:00', '86:01:12'))
```

It gives me a error that.

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

Searching for a solution from Saturday and couldn't find it.

Some one help me out, how can I convert the time datatype which is greater then 24 hours to seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best way, but you can basically explode it to hours, minutes and seconds, then add them all up. If I understand right what you wish to do is to convert a time format to seconds.

This works on 2008 R2

```
DECLARE @inputTime AS VARCHAR(10) = '86:01:12'

DECLARE @timeSec AS INT = SUBSTRING(@inputTime,1,2) * 3600 + SUBSTRING(@inputTime,4,2) * 60 + SUBSTRING(@inputTime,7,2) 

PRINT @timeSec
```

You can do this as a one-liner, to nest it in any of your queries:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('86:01:12',1,2) * 3600 + SUBSTRING('86:01:12',4,2) * 60 + SUBSTRING('86:01:12',7,2)
```

As you can see it will treat it as a String, get the first two chars as hours, multiply by 3600 (60 seconds in a minute * 60 minutes in an hour). Next take the minutes and multiply them by 60 (60 seconds in a minute), and last add the seconds up, which is * 1 since that is the resolution you are looking for.

For easier use, you can create a function, and use that onwards to make your code less messy:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.stampSeconds (@inputTime VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @timeSec AS INT = SUBSTRING(@inputTime,1,2) * 3600 + SUBSTRING(@inputTime,4,2) * 60 + SUBSTRING(@inputTime,7,2) 

    RETURN @timeSec

END
```

Which you can then use like:

```
SELECT dbo.stampSeconds ('29:07:01')
```

Comment: I have series of columns and also need to do some calculations on the seconds derived. Is there any other short method we can do it? What you provided does gives me the correct result, but is this the only shortest way we can do it?

Comment: @Dee I have updated the answer - this way you would introduce a function to your database, that will allow you to call it anytime you wish to use it. So for example, you could ````SELECT dbo.stampSeconds(column1) - dbo.stampSeconds(column2)````