# SQL Server : help required in Time data type

Tags: sql-server

First of, I'm new to SQL Server (but experienced with PostgreSQL). Kindly excuse if the same question has been asked earlier.

I have a column in a table which contains a column with time data type.

And I upload the data to the table using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Also I posted earlier on how to convert the time to seconds which is greater 24 hours from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840175/mssql-extract-second-from-time).

But now I'm facing with another problem, that is the data format of the time data type which is uploaded to the table.

I have a value in that column which is `01-01-1900 14:58`. As the column data type is time, the value is updated only with the hour, minute and second part.

But I want the value to be updated in this format which is the correct value `38:58:46`.

And as it's a time data type, this is the value is being updated in the table `14:58:46`.

When I use the text function to convert it to seconds like this.

```
SELECT 
    (SUBSTRING('14:58:46', 1, 2) * 60 * 60) + 
    (SUBSTRING('14:58:46', 4, 2) * 60) + 
    SUBSTRING('14:58:46', 7, 2)
```

The result is `53926` this, but actually it should be `140326`.

Some one please help me out to overcome this issue with the datatype?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SQL server time data type represents a time of day based on a 24 hour clock. How is it possible to get a time of 38:58:46?

Comment: That is not a timestamp. It's a a column that contains number of hours scheduled for something. In general 38 hours.

Comment: To SQL server, a TIME column means a time of day. If you need to store a duration, use an integer column and store the number of seconds. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb677243.aspx

Comment: @Marc - I dont' wanted to format the raw data. I wanted to upload it directly to the table and from the table can I convert it to second? This is what I'm looking for. As I don't do any formatting or changes in the raw data. Errorness in the raw data will be reduced. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: You already have the code to convert the table value to seconds. Your problem is that you're asking a TIME field to store 140326 seconds, when it can only store 86400. It seems to me that if you want to store a value representing a duration > 1 day, you should use a different data type in the table to do it.

Comment: Thank you. And yes I did use a different data type. I converted the number to float and used float data type. While calculating the SQL. I take the sum directly and then multiply with 86400 and it did the work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query.

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING('38:58:46', 1, 2) AS bigint)* 60 * 60 + 
       CAST(SUBSTRING('38:58:46', 4, 2) AS bigint) * 60 +  
       CAST(SUBSTRING('38:58:46', 7, 2) AS bigint)
```

this returns 140326.

Comment: My question is that how can I get this `38:58:46` value? As my data type is time, I'm getting `14:58:46`.